# Validation accuracy is low and not increasing while training accuracy is increasing

Tags: python, validation, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a newbie to Keras and machine learning in general. I’m trying to build a classification model using the Sequential model. After some experiments, I see that my validation accuracy behavior is very low and not increasing, although the training accuracy works well. I added regularization parameters to the layers and dropouts also in between the layers. Still, the behavior exists. Here’s my code.

```
from keras.regularizers import l2
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding="SAME", activation="relu", input_shape=[512,1],kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.1))) # 一定要加 input shape
keras.layers.Dropout=0.35
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=1,activity_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="softmax",activity_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
```

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])
```

```
Ahistory = model.fit(train_x, trainy, epochs=300, 
                    validation_split = 0.2, 
                    batch_size = 16)
```

And here is the final results I got.

[image: Training accuracy & Validation accuracy]

What is the reason behind this.? How do I fine-tune the model.?

Comment: Can you share some information about your problem, the data you have?

Comment: And why you didn't `add` the `Dropout` layer? Also, you are splitting your `train_x` during the fit although you already have a validation data: `trainy`. Either don't split your data before and use `validation_split`, or split it before and remove the `validation_split`

Comment: @emremrah, I have added the dropout layer as above. I didn't split the data during the fit and I have separately uploaded the training data(train_x and trainy)  before in the code. train_x and trainy refers to the data and the corresponding labels since this is a classification model. And I added validation_split to generate the validation data. Is there anything wrong in my procedure?

Comment: Ah, sorry sorry, what was I thinking... Forget about the validation thing I said, you are doing it right. But why didn't you add the dropout layer as `model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.35))`, are you sure it will work the way you did?

Comment: @emremrah, When I use `model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.35))` it gives the error as SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression. Is there any possible reason for this. ?   I am using tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0